# Powershell issue with Test-path

Tags: powershell

I am trying to see which computers have the teams folder. I have a .csv file called pc3.csv with all of the computer names listed. While my script runs, the output only shows the computer names followed by False (which is by design of test-path if at least one of the paths is missing.) I would like it to show the computer name and whether or not it shows the path. Here is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
[CmdletBinding()] param()
Get-Content C:\script\pc3.csv
[string[]]$Computer = $env:computername

foreach ($Computer in $Computername) {
$a = Test-Path -path '\\$computer\c$\users\*\appdata\local\microsoft\teams'
 IF (-not $a) {Write-Host "$Computer this is not true"} ELSE {Write-Host "$Computer This is true"}
 }
```

Comment: 1) Your `Get-Content` is not being stored in a variable, so PowerShell just outputs it. 2) If the file contains just text lines and is not a comma-separated values file (that's what CSV means, after all), then you should name it `.txt` to avoid confusion. 3) Your `foreach` loop only looks at the current computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what value `$computername` is supposed to have that you are iterating. You are supposed to have all the contents from the text file loaded in to a variable. That variable would have an array of each line from your Get-Content command.

Once you have the list of all the computers, and "Administrative" access to view c$\users*, then you can run the following snippet. If you do not have access to all the systems, you wont be able to get true details.

```
$computerList =  Get-Content C:\script\pc3.csv
foreach($computer in $computerList) {
  if (Test-Path "\\$computer\c$\users\*\appdata\local\microsoft\teams") {
    Write-Host "$computer This is true"
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "$computer This is not true"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jawad and @Bill_Stewart. The pc3.csv file has the computer names and I already have administrator access. This really helped me make the progress necessary to gather which computers I need to disable Microsoft Teams on without manually checking each one.